# Android java using locationlistener but can't toast the locations on the app

Tags: java, android, static, handler, toast

First of all i'm a newbie, started programming android java about a month ago, so please be patient if i dont understand complex answers.(programmed in C earlier so my expressions may be used from that language)
 I got stuck on a problem where i want to write a toast with the locations on the app. I have a locationlistener that save the coordinates in variables. What i want to do is to send them to a function or a handler that can write toasts. I get errors because it says that the variables from locationlistener are static, so the function must also be static, but when i change that the toast doesnt work
My code looks like this :

```
public class GPS extends ActionBarActivity{
private LocationListener locationListener=null;
private static final String TAG = "";
private InputStream mmInStream = null;
private Context mcontext;

public void read(final LocationManager locationManager) {
    Looper.prepare();
        try {
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager
                    .GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);
            Log.d(TAG, "7");
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Looper.loop();
}
public void toscreen(String longitude, String latitude) {
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(longitude));
 //   MainActivity.toastMessage(latitude);
}

public void hit(BluetoothSocket BtSocket, final LocationManager locationManager) {
    try {
        mmInStream = BtSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            read(locationManager);
        }
    }).start();
}

private class MyLocationListener extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        try {
            String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " +
                            loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);

            Log.d(TAG, "9");
            toscreen(longitude, latitude);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

I try to use toast in "toscreen" and a handler in Mainactivity that looks like this :

```
    public void toastMessage(final String msg) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you would get errors about referencing static variables, could you elaborate on which error you are getting?
The only clue I get is this commented-out code "MainActivity.toastMessage(latitude)" which seems to reference toastMessage as a static method, which would not work as it's not a static method - and you don't even seem to have any MainActivity class, or at least it's not shown here.

However, I see several other strange things.

1. Why are you using a Looper? Loopers are used in handler threads that should block while waiting for events. Is this what you want? You are requesting location updates to be supplied to your listener callback, but I see no reason to have a thread running as a blocking event looper?
2. Why does your LocationListener extend ActionBarActivity? It makes no sense.
3. Don't use getBaseContext, use getApplicationContext() or the activity itself as the context in the call to Toast.makeText.
4. Toasts can only be used from Handler threads - usually you use Toasts from the main thread. If you have a worker thread that needs to display a toast you could post a runnable to the main handler without creating any new Looper with something like this:

   `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(...).show();
       }
   });`

(alternatively you could create a Handler object in your activity's onCreate and store it as a member, as this will be called from the main thread.)

As there are numerous issues here it's hard to help. Please clarify what your exact problem is.

**Edit:** It seems I may have been slightly wrong about LocationManager, it seems that it does not always call the listener methods on the main thread, but rather on the thread that called requestUpdates. That means you either need to call requestUpdates from the main thread and handle the callbacks on the main thread as well, OR call requestUpdates from a HandlerThread (that inherently has a looper) and handle callbacks from there. I really don't see any strong reason for the latter approach so I would recommend calling requestUpdates from the main thread. However, if there is some heavy processing or blocking I/O you should of course *then* spawn a worker thread for that work.

Comment: 1.When i remove the Looper from the read function i get these errors : java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(),
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200),
at dogtracker.nystart.GPS.read(GPS.java:60),
at dogtracker.nystart.GPS$1.run(GPS.java:81)
2. 3. fixed
4. When i send my coordinates in variables to MainActivity.toastmessage (where i have rest of the code, doesnt affect what i want to do in this code but i can send if you need it?) it says "non-static method 'toastmessage' cannot be referenced from static content"

Comment: And if i change it to : public static void toastMessage(final String msg)
It says the same about this line : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: 1. You should consider these errors as hints about something else being seriously wrong. These errors are there because you are trying to show a toast from a non-looper thread. Rather than transforming your worker thread into a looper thread for the purpose of being able to show toasts, you should show the toasts from the main thread, using the technique I listed above.

Comment: 4. Well, yes you ARE trying to call a method as if it's static although it's not. And if you make the method static, it cannot reference your member "handler" since that is not a static member. The question you should ask yourself is, does this method have to be in MainActivity at all? Couldn't you call Toast directly from your "GPS" activity class?

You typically should not have static methods on your activities in the first place as activities have their own defined lifecycle managed by the system and if your start keeping static members around you might inadvertently cause memory leaks.

Comment: I mean no disrespect here at all, but I would highly recommend you read up on Java static methods (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), perhaps Android threads (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) and perhaps also Android activity life-cycle (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) if you haven't already, as these are fundamental in understanding some very basic concepts. Getting passed that will save you a lot of time spent on trial and error and is well worth the effort.

Comment: I think I was wrong about how requestUpdates works, so I updated my answer. You either need to call requestUpdates from the main thread or from a proper HandlerThread. I would recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method as this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // show my toast here

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems I found in your code:

- You made `MyLocationListener` extend `ActionBarActivity`. There absolutely is no need for that, it only introduces problems. You cannot simply instantiate a subclass of `Activity` yourself, all functionality related to `Contexts` won't work if you do. You are using `getBaseContext()` in a subclass of `Activity` that you instantiate yourself, so there's the problem.

  The solution is to remove the `extends ActionBarActivity`:

  ```
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
  ```
- Is `GPS` actually used as an `Activity`? I guess not. It should not extend `ActionBarActivity` then.
- You don't need any of the `Thread` and `Looper` stuff. All `LocationManager` calls are sent from a system background thread to the main thread. You don't have to create your own background thread.
- Your code fragments don't provide enough details for finding all problems.

Comment: I've fixed the problems you mention except the Looper, i posted the errors as an answer on JHH.
The main problem is still that i cant write a toast with the variables, i have 2 java files where the other one is MainActivity thats doesnt really do anything to my GPS class., would you still need the whole code?

Comment: I updated my answer and comments above because I misunderstood one thing about requestUpdates.
Given this, I think you should call requestUpdates from the main thread. This means also LocationListener will be called on the main thread, which in turn means using a Toast directly is no problem.
However, you also seem to have some I/O related to bluetooth which might be blocking and could need a separate worker thread, but how you use threads is not visible from your code snippet.